# Camunda : Connect to sql database

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, camunda

I want to connect sql server databse via camunda( more clearly i want to write data parsed by script processor into spl server databse) i have added this configurations inside my conf/server.xml

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/ProcessEngine"
         auth="Container"
         type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
         factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
         uniqueResourceName="process-engine"
         driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
           url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/camunda;MVCC=TRUE;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=0;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
          defaultTransactionIsolation="READ_COMMITTED"
        username="sa"  
       password="****"
      maxActive="20"
        minIdle="5" />
```

and i want to know what should i configure or add inside my camunda project or camunda modeller to make my project write this data inside databse tabeles?

Can you link me any example or tutoria whiach can help me implement this logica i have already read thsi https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.4/user-guide/process-engine/database/
ALSO  HERE ARE  SOM  SUBJECTS  I AM INTERESTED  IN:

1. if is it possible to write and get data by post and get request from http rest connector
   2.if there is more flexible way to do this operation without rest service?

Comment: Be cautious about isolation level. SQL server with Camunda prefer `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPHOT`. You can read from https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.4/user-guide/process-engine/database/#custom-configuration-for-microsoft-sql-server.

Answer (score 1):

Use a service task in camunda BPM diagram and make that task implements a Java delegate. Inside that Java delegate class take a connection using JDBC.. now you can write and read the data!